# Oracle 11G EM not working on Windows 7

Tags: oracle11gr2

I have installed oracle 11G release 2 on my Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit computer but I am unable to run em. When I login it generates an error 'Internal error has occcured check log file for details' Following I have observed:

1. Service `ORACLEDBConsoleorcl` has not started.
2. When I execute emctl start dnconsole, it gives me an error "A specific service error occured: 2" followed by "more help is available by typing NET HELPMSG "
3. After the installation database configuration assistant  gave me a warning of "Error starting database control. Please execute the following commands

   - Set the enviroment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name
   - `c:\app\henry\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emctl.bat start dbconsole`
4. Following is the detail of enoms

```
2011-05-30 13:05:05,601 [EMUI_13_05_05_/console/database/instance/sitemap] ERROR perf.sitemap initializeGeneral.580 - Failed to initialize object: ORA-20206: 
ORA-06512: at "SYSMAN.EMD_DATABASE", line 1297
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 1

2011-05-30 13:05:05,788 [MetricCollector:HOMETAB_THREAD600:60] ERROR rt.DbMetricCollectorTarget _getAllData.344 - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getURL(EMDClient.java:1570)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1266)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1242)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getResponseForRequest(EMDClient.java:1689)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getMetrics(EMDClient.java:981)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab._getAllData(DbHomeTab.java:340)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab.getData(DbHomeTab.java:154)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCached.collectCachedData(MetricCached.java:416)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread._collectCachedData(MetricCollectorThread.java:605)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread.run(MetricCollectorThread.java:325)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2011-05-30 13:05:05,788 [MetricCollector:HOMETAB_THREAD600:60] ERROR rt.DbMetricCollectorTarget _getAllData.344 - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getURL(EMDClient.java:1570)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1266)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getConnection(EMDClient.java:1242)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getResponseForRequest(EMDClient.java:1689)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.comm.EMDClient.getMetrics(EMDClient.java:981)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab._getAllData(DbHomeTab.java:340)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.rt.DbHomeTab.getData(DbHomeTab.java:154)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCached.collectCachedData(MetricCached.java:416)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread._collectCachedData(MetricCollectorThread.java:605)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.perf.metric.eng.MetricCollectorThread.run(MetricCollectorThread.java:325)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2011-05-30 13:05:05,788 [EMUI_13_05_05_/console/database/instance/sitemap] ERROR perf.sitemap initializeFromAgent.1047 - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.dtd.ValueRow.getNumValue(ValueRow.java:330)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.emd.dtd.ValueRow.getNumValue(ValueRow.java:366)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.smap.DBInstanceInitializer.initializeFromAgent(DBInstanceInitializer.java:998)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.smap.DBInstanceInitializer.initialize(DBInstanceInitializer.java:395)
    at oracle.sysman.emo.smap.DBInstance.init(DBInstance.java:643)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.SitemapController.getBean(SitemapController.java:3570)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.SitemapController.getInstanceBean(SitemapController.java:2963)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.SitemapController.logFeatureUsageHomePage(SitemapController.java:6384)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.SitemapController.onDoLoad(SitemapController.java:3058)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.BaseController.handleEvent(BaseController.java:1306)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.PageHandler.handleRequest(PageHandler.java:577)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.RootController.handleRequest(RootController.java:235)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.BaseController.handleRequest(BaseController.java:1238)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.DBControllerResolver.handleRequest(DBControllerResolver.java:139)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.myDoGet(EMServlet.java:787)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.doGet(EMServlet.java:343)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.Console.doGet(Console.java:319)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.EMRepLoginFilter.doFilter(EMRepLoginFilter.java:208)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.HandleRepDownFilter.doFilter(HandleRepDownFilter.java:165)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.BrowserVersionFilter.doFilter(BrowserVersionFilter.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMRedirectFilter.doFilter(EMRedirectFilter.java:102)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitFilter.doFilter(ContextInitFilter.java:357)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:621)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:370)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:871)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:453)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2011-05-30 13:05:05,803 [EMUI_13_05_05_/console/database/instance/sitemap] ERROR svlt.PageHandler handleRequest.639 - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.sysman.util.jdk.VersionUtil.compareVersion(VersionUtil.java:63)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.SitemapController.setRequestAttributes(SitemapController.java:1355)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.BaseController.handleEvent(BaseController.java:1391)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.PageHandler.handleRequest(PageHandler.java:577)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.RootController.handleRequest(RootController.java:235)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.BaseController.handleRequest(BaseController.java:1238)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.DBControllerResolver.handleRequest(DBControllerResolver.java:139)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.myDoGet(EMServlet.java:787)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.doGet(EMServlet.java:343)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.Console.doGet(Console.java:319)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.EMRepLoginFilter.doFilter(EMRepLoginFilter.java:208)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15)
    at oracle.sysman.db.adm.inst.HandleRepDownFilter.doFilter(HandleRepDownFilter.java:165)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.BrowserVersionFilter.doFilter(BrowserVersionFilter.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMRedirectFilter.doFilter(EMRedirectFilter.java:102)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitFilter.doFilter(ContextInitFilter.java:357)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:621)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:370)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:871)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:453)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you didn't set up Windows 7 to allow Oracle to run without issues before installing it (opening ports, disabling UAC, installing JDK etc).

This blog post explains the installation process in detail [Oracle 11gR2 on Windows 7](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/12/29/oracle-11gr2-on-windows-7/).  Complete all the Windows 7 configuration steps and try the install again with 11.2.0.3.