# Error code 2 starting OracleDbConsole service

Tags: oracle11gr2

I installed Oracle DB 11g, 
everything was working well, but suddenly process
`OracleDbConsoleorcl` didn't start anymore, I try
manually but it always shows this message:

```
Windows could not start OracleDbConsoleorcl on
Local Computer. If this is a non-Microsoft service,
contact the service vendor, and refer the service
specific error code 2
```

What should I do??

Comment: Is your question different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179053/oracle-11g-em-not-working-on-windows-7?rq=1 ? Please proceed per that question and include information how your situation is different (log excerpts etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command to check the issues/configuration status of OracleDBConsoleorcle:

```
emctl status dbconsole
```

You can then configure accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle 11g: Windows could not start the OracleDBConsoleorcl on Local Computer

I was using the Oracle 11g in my Windows 7 Professional system for few days..  Suddenly, I was not able to use the sql developer to connect the schema/user.

I found that the Oracle... services were down in the Windows services windows.

a) Oracle ORCL VSS Writer Service - running
b) OracleDBConsoleorcle - not running
c) OracleJobSchedulerORCL - not running
d) OracleServiceORCL - not running

When I started the OracleDBConsoleoracle, it thrown a error "Windows could not start the OracleDBConsoleorcl on Local Computer".

(Below solution is worked for me, based on the various fo rum threads)...

- a. go to C:.......\product\11.1.0\db_1\oc4j\j2ee
- b. copy paste the folder: OC4J_DBConsole_192.168.x.y_orcl, two times
- c. rename one of the two new folder as OC4J_DBConsole_**localhost**_orcl
- d. rename the other one as OC4J_DBConsole__orcl

after making these changes and a reboot, it started to running.........

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the server IP was changed, I've placed the IP back and It's working!