# Oracle does not start service while attempt to restart Oracle in windows 7

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am using windows 7 64 bit Operating System and I am using Oracle DB 11G Release 2. Uncertainly My OS stop the service of Oracle.When I try to restart the oracle service then the following message is showing. "windows could not start the oracledbconsoleorcl on local computer. For more Information review the system log.If this is a non microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2"

Now My problem is:

1. I could not login to Oracle from Oracle SQL Plus
2. I need to backup some important data.
   Please help me. Is there any option to start the oracle service or backup my sql data?
   Though I try by following method. here's the link [Error code 2 starting OracleDbConsole service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693755/error-code-2-starting-oracledbconsole-service)

Comment: try to start the service from command prompt , by running in the administrator mode, 
use,

    net start oracleservice<dbnam>

Comment: Check the Windows event log (as suggested by the error message) and check the Oracle alert log.